# Get Private Key with openssl rand /dev/urandom

Tags: openssl

I want to generate a private key using rand openssl option.

I'm using osx, and I know that there isn't different between urandom e random, but I don't think that this is a point

I use that command

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 rand  /dev/urandom -out test.pem
```

But I receive this message

> unknown option 'rand'

even with

-rand

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -rand /dev/urandom -out test.pem
```

> unknown option '-rand'

I try this command to check the rand

```
openssl rand -base64 6
```

and it works.

```
openssl version
LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [LibreSSL](https://www.libressl.org/). This is not really OpenSSL. According to the [documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/openssl.1#ECPARAM) it does *not* support the `-rand` argument.